# Azure SignalR Serverless and dotnet core API application

Tags: azure, .net-core, signalr

We are attempting to get Azure SignalR serverless to with a dotnet core API application.  With "default" SignalR, we ran into scaling issues in Azure as server instances behind an API App would continue to receive socket connections even as its CPU increases.  There is no way to currently to change load balancing behavior or to take an instance out of traffic.  As such, we've looked to use "serverless", however, all documentation points to using Azure Functions.  However, given that serverless uses webhooks and such, we *should* be able to use anything that can take an HTTP request.  We already have our APIs setup so getting this to work against out APIs is preferred.

Update 1

Effectively, we're looking for support for serverless that Functions get but for APIs.  Functions have triggers and Serverless Hubs to inherit from, etc etc.  These things handle negotiate calls and deserialization of negotiation data and all the other things SigR has to do.  We're looking for something similar for, I guess, API controllers.

Thanks!

Comment: the webhook will be triggered by http request

Comment: yes, let me update my question to be more specific